# Existence of special diffeomorphism

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Assume $F: M \times [0,T) \rightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is solution of some flow like
$$
(\partial_t F(q,t))^\bot= H(F(q,t)) ~~~(q,t)\in M \times  [0,T)
$$
$M$ is a n-dim smooth Rie-manifold. $H$ is mean curvature. In fact, this flow is equal to mean curvature flow up to tangential diffeomorphisms. For proving this , we  need a diffeomorphism $\varphi : M \times[0 ,T )\rightarrow M $ satisfy 
$$
\nabla _q F(\varphi(p,t),t)(\partial _t \varphi(p,t))=-(\partial_t F(q,t))^\top
$$
But I can't see why $\varphi$ always existence ?  $\nabla$ is Euclidean connection.

This question  origin from 82 page of Mean Curvature Flow of Cylindrical  Graphs

Comment: You should be able to write this as the problem of integrating a time-dependent vector field on $M$, which is a standard topic in differential topology. See e.g. Hirsch's chapter on isotopies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the notation in the post, nor the relation to connections. However, here is how you can construct the desired reparametrization.

Let $F:M\times[0,t)\to\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ satisfy your condition. That is, $$(\partial_t F(q,t))^\bot= H(F(q,t)) ~~~(q,t)\in M \times  [0,T).$$
Then there is a time-dependent vector field $X_t\in\mathfrak{X}(M),\;t\in[0,T),$ satisfying 
$$
H(F(q,t))-\partial_tF(q,t)=d(F_t)_q(X_t(q)).
$$
Let $\varphi:M\times[0,T)\to M$ be the flow of $X_t$. Then, it follows from the chain rule that the reparametrized family of embeddings $F'_t:=F_t\circ\varphi_t$ is mean curvature flow.

It should be noted that the flow of the vector field $X_t$ is not necessarily defined on all $M\times[0,T)$. This issue can be resolved, for example, by requiring $M$ to be compact.

Comment: What is the mean of $d(F_t)_q(X_t(q))$ ?   $d$ is exterior differentiation ?

Comment: @lanse7pty In this context, $d$ denotes the differential of $F_t$. Some authors call $d(F_t)_q(X_t(q))$ the pushforward of $X_t$ by $F_t$.

Comment: Sorry, when I  verify $F_t'$ is mean curvature flow,  I got stuck.  $\partial_t F(\varphi(q,t),t)= [H(\varphi(q,t),t) - d(F(\varphi(q,t),t))(X(\varphi(q,t),t))] \partial_t\varphi(q,t)=[H(\varphi(q,t),t) - d(F(\varphi(q,t),t))(X(\varphi(q,t),t))]  X(q,t)$,    then I don't know how to do it .