# Equivalence class of the normal flow

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, mean-curvature-flows

Consider a compact manifold $M^n$ embedding in  $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. We can deform it by some geometric flow. A kind of all, we only move it in the normal direct, for example, mean curvature
$$
\partial_tF=-H\nu
$$
Another kind, we move it in the normal direct and position vector direct, for example, the area preserving mean curvature flow
$$
\partial_t F= -H\nu + \frac{h}{n}F
$$
From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362189/existence-of-special-diffeomorphism), I know the moving in non-normal direct can be decomposed into normal moving and tangent moving. So I feel some flow is equal to normal flow. Assume I have a flow
$$
\partial_t F = \varphi F+ \psi \nu
$$
and $F: M^n\times [0,T)\rightarrow \mathbb R^{n+1}$ is solution of it. Then
$$
\partial_t F = \varphi F^\top + (\varphi\langle F ,\nu\rangle +\psi)\nu
$$
where $F^\top$ is tangential component of $F$. Then, finding a vector field $X_t\in\mathfrak{X}(M^n)$ such that 
$$
\partial_t F - (\varphi\langle F ,\nu\rangle +\psi)\nu =  d(F_t)(X_t)
$$
Let $x_t:M^n\times [0,T)\rightarrow M^n$ be the flow of $X_t$, and $\widetilde F_t = F_t \circ x_t$, according to [Amitai Yuval's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2362189/existence-of-special-diffeomorphism), I guess I have
$$
\partial_t \widetilde F =(\varphi\langle \widetilde F ,\widetilde \nu\rangle +\psi)\widetilde \nu
$$
In fact, I don't know how to calculate the above equality.  Then, any flow liking 
$$
\partial_t F = \varphi F+ \psi \nu
$$
is equal to a normal flow which has form 
$$
\partial_t \widetilde F =(\varphi\langle \widetilde F ,\widetilde \nu\rangle +\psi)\widetilde \nu
$$
whether I am right ?